# Disable 301 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, curl

I have directory on my server, for example `https://myserver/dir/subdir/` with `index.php` file in it. When I am requesting `https://myserver/dir/subdir/` through curl its fine, but when I am requesting `https://myserver/dir/subdir` without the last slash, it returns **301 status - removed permanently**. In browser it works fine - it redirects me to `https://myserver/dir/subdir/` with slash. But curl doesnt work. How do I resolve this?

Comment: post some code can help

Answer (score 0):

By default curl does not follow redirects. Use the `-L` flag to tell curl to follow 301s.